# Twig's custom filters aren't working

Tags: symfony, twig

I created a simple Twig filter from the docs:

```
public function getFilters() {

        return array(
            'price' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'priceFilter'),
        );
    }


    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$' . $price;

        return $price;
    }
```

It's registered in the config (since in that file I have a function that works well):

```
services:
    sybio.twig_extension:
        class: %sybio.twig_extension.class%
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

But it doesn't work, saying `The filter "price" does not exist`. How come?

Comment: What if you write down your class like `class: Sybio\Twig_Extension\Price_Filter`

Comment: What's your `getName()` method?

Comment: Paste full extension class and parameters section from your config.

Answer (score 3):

Few things first make sure you have this function in the twig class

```
public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
```

Secondly try changing this to the full class name for debugging then you can change it

`class: %sybio.twig_extension.class%` to `class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension`

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and I was returning the same name for two different filter classes in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could use my simple example.

class filter:

```
namespace Project\Bundle\Twig;

class Price extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'price' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'priceFilter'),
        );
    }

    public function priceFilter($arg)
    {
        return number_format($arg);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'price';
    }
}
```

config:

```
services:
    bundle.twig.price:
        class: Project\Bundle\Twig\Price
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```